# JavaFX: How do i remove the prompt text in the ComboBox's list?

Tags: combobox, javafx-2, javafx

I have a combo box that has prompt text "Test".
[image: combobox]

Say I want to remove the prompt text in the list only like in the image below, how should I do it? 
[image: comboboxclear]

Thank you.

Comment: You do not want to remove the Object from the model/list? And it should be visible inside the comboBox once it is selected but not inside the popup? <- Right?

Comment: Hey Hendrik, thanks. For these cases, "Test" is  just a display and not yet in the model/list because I used cbo.setPromptText("Test"); and not cbo.setItems(listContainingTest); I mean, for the images above, cbo is an empty combobox.

Comment: I think the best way is to create your custom cellfactory and write a new ListCell class. Here you can add some logic

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. Didn't realize cellFactory can also change the prompt text. :)

Comment: No problem :) I added a Answer. Maybe you can mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to create your custom cellfactory and write a new ListCell class. Here you can add some logic:
   http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ListCell.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can simply do this by using this method:

```
cbo.setPromptText(null);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#setPromptText(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, as checked, what happens when i do that is the prompt on the button also disappears

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is with this line:
`Some_ComboBox.getItems().remove(Some_ComboBox.getItems().size()-1);`